# How does being revived affect the K/D in Battlefield 4?

Tags: battlefield-4

Some situations:

1. I killed an enemy, but he got revived. Will it count as a kill?
2. I died and got revived. Will it count as a death?
3. I killed an enemy, he got revived and I killed him again. 2 kills?
4. I died, got revived and died again. 2 deaths?

Thanks guys!

Comment: As far as I understand, yes, yes, no, no. Not 100% though.

Comment: Phew, have to look around for that. I can only say, that if you die, you will lose a ticket **after you spawned again**. So you save one ticket by getting revived.

Comment: I thought the following: 1) yes, 2) no, 3) yes, 4) no (1 death)

Comment: Side note: In terms of each teams' number of tickets, the ticket-count only decreases when a player starts a new life from the redeploy menu. (In very close games, sometimes teammates should simply wait in limbo.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know it works like this:

- Player is killed: This adds one kill. but no death yet.
- Player receives a revive offer: This has no effect on any stats.

From then on there are multiple possibilities:

- Player declines and spawns new: This costs the team one ticket and the player receives one death.
- Player accepts, but is killed: This adds one kill. The player is no longer revivable, unless the last revive happened more than 20 seconds (or 10 seconds?) ago. This has no effect on tickets, but the player receives one death, if he's killed before being able to be revived once more. One ticket is used once he respawns though.
- Player accepts and survives: This has no effect on any stats (although I think your "in one life" stats continue counting).

Comment: I am fairly sure that if a player is killed, the victim does not get a death until he/she respawns (or at least a sort of "bleed out" timer expires). Hopefully I'll have time to test out a few scenarios tonight. [_My interpretion of how it works._](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tkd9SWiN)

Comment: Just for absolute accuracy, a revive will add a point to the revive stats for that player and to the match stats ;)

Comment: Great answer! Do you have any sources?

Comment: @Lyrical Nice, edit this answer if you confirm!

Comment: @DavidYell Cool!

Comment: @Lyrical Yes, you're correct. The death is only added once you respawn/go back to spawn screen. Played too much Dust 514 recently I guess. :)